# other interface connected to linux bridge not receiving multicast packet

Tags: networking, 20.04, lxc, network-bridge, ipv4

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Bridge Info

```
sudo brctl show
bridge name        bridge id            STP enabled    interfaces
1-299057404        8000.e2808b5d2504    no              SN1DT299057404
                                                        ifp-0-0-37
```

netstat

```
anil@srv07-tst:~$ netstat -gn | grep ifp-0-0-37
ifp-0-0-37      1      224.0.0.1
ifp-0-0-37      1      ff02::1:ff5d:2504
ifp-0-0-37      1      ff02::1
ifp-0-0-37      1      ff01::1
anil@srv07-tst:~$ netstat -gn | grep 1-299057404
1-299057404     1      ff02::1:ff03:ff69
1-299057404     1      ff02::1
1-299057404     1      ff01::1
anil@srv07-tst:~$ netstat -gn | grep SN1DT299057404
SN1DT299057404  1      ff02::1:ffda:bf17
SN1DT299057404  1      ff02::1
SN1DT299057404  1      ff01::1
anil@srv07-tst:~$
```

ifconfig

```
anil@srv07-tst:~$ sudo ifconfig 1-299057404
1-299057404: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet6 fe80::70ad:a6ff:fe03:ff69  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e2:80:8b:5d:25:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 67707334  bytes 5145618990 (5.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 154  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 2002 (2.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

anil@srv07-tst:~$ sudo ifconfig ifp-0-0-37 
ifp-0-0-37: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet6 fe80::e080:8bff:fe5d:2504  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e2:80:8b:5d:25:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34654  bytes 2712322 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42742  bytes 6036238 (6.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

anil@srv07-tst:~$ sudo ifconfig SN1DT299057404
SN1DT299057404: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet6 fe80::fc5b:c2ff:feda:bf17  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:5b:c2:da:bf:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 67726734  bytes 6095402360 (6.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5137  bytes 328194 (328.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

From LXC container:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni SN1DT299057404 -e -c5
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on SN1DT299057404, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:03:50.998028 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.10.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:50.998044 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0b, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.11.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:50.998051 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.12.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:50.998060 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0d, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.13.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:50.998067 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.14.65056: UDP, length 48
5 packets captured
40 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

To Bridge :

```
sudo tcpdump -ni 1-299057404 -e -c5
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on 1-299057404, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:03:32.394260 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.10.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:32.394295 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0b, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.11.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:32.394303 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.12.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:32.394613 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0d, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.13.65056: UDP, length 48
23:03:32.394620 da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5 > 01:00:5e:1b:48:0e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 198.18.73.251.65056 > 232.27.72.14.65056: UDP, length 48
5 packets captured
53 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

The other interface on which i was expecting multicast packet :

```
sudo tcpdump -ni ifp-0-0-37 -e -c5
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ifp-0-0-37, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:04:07.345457 18:be:92:a1:09:25 > da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 100.100.1.1.65056 > 80.156.101.2.65056: UDP, length 48
23:04:07.585244 18:be:92:a1:09:25 > 01:80:c2:00:00:0e, ethertype LLDP (0x88cc), length 98: LLDP, length 84: rtbrick
23:04:08.345369 18:be:92:a1:09:25 > da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 100.100.1.1.65056 > 80.156.101.2.65056: UDP, length 48
23:04:09.346033 18:be:92:a1:09:25 > da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 100.100.1.1.65056 > 80.156.101.2.65056: UDP, length 48
23:04:10.345611 18:be:92:a1:09:25 > da:8a:ba:4b:8a:f5, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: 100.100.1.1.65056 > 80.156.101.2.65056: UDP, length 48
5 packets captured
5 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Any suggestions, clue, advice or pointers would be much appreciated...

Comment: Are you running a supported Ubuntu release? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Sure waltinator, this is my first question... I have updated the query